# ListView with Button Onclick Method

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make a list of checkboxes with CustomAdapter, and I am following the tutorial  [here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html) , and my code looks like this :

```
    dataAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.customrow, CheckboxArrayList);
    ListView listView = (ListView) FragmentView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           //.....
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked on Row: " + Checkbox.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

This method is only called when I am pressed the margin area outside the checkbox.
How do I make this onClick method to happen on the checkbox itself, not the list entry?  Thanks

Comment: In that you should go for call back. Define one interface and try to make a call back which will call the method defined in your parent class(Activity/Fragment or whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set a listener on the Checkbox control itself, not the ListView.

```
// in your ListView adapter
public View getView(int positon, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  // inflate your cell
  View cell = ...

  // find your checkbox
  CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)cell.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

  // set an OnCheckedChangeListener on the checkbox
  checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, Boolean isChecked)
   {
   }
  });

.
.
.
```

Use a ViewHolder pattern to do this more efficiently if you're not already doing so.  The ViewHolder will allow you to keep a reference to the row/position #, as well as sharing a listener for the CheckedChange event.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Could you show me how to access the position number of the checkbox with ViewHolder?

Answer (score 0):

Use setOnCheckedChangeListener() to get check box event